# How to test for flash using cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am writing cucumber tests for my RoR app and I need to test for a flash to appear:

```
<p class='flashnotice flash'>Message was successfully sent.</p>
```

However, I just can't find a solution that works.  I've tried:

```
  page.should have_selector('p', :class => 'flashnotice flash') do
    page.should have_content fartknocker
  end
```

But that returns an error on :class and says I can't use that.  Can someone show me the right way to test for flash?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this style instead

```
page.should have_css('.flashnotice', text: "Message was successfully sent")
```

Comment: I got `page.should have_css('.flashnotice', text: "Message was successfully sent")`